# GAE NDB example useage of Future.wait_all()

Tags: google-app-engine

sorry for my ignorance but my expectation is that this would work:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from models import myModels

delete_futures = []
delete_futures.append(ndb.delete_multi_async(myModels.Kind1.query().fetch(999999, keys_only=True)))
delete_futures.append(ndb.delete_multi_async(myModels.Kind2.query().fetch(999999, keys_only=True)))

ndb.Future.wait_all(delete_futures)
```

but it throws "TypeError: list objects are unhashable".

Comment: Bear in mind that this isn't terribly async - fetching the list of keys is still going to be done synchronously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

perhaps use .extend to create a single list rather then a list of lists?

> Wait until all Futures in the passed list are done.

Not expecting your passed list of lists maybe.

```
delete_futures = []
delete_futures.extend(ndb.delete_multi_async(myModels.Kind1.query().fetch(999999,          keys_only=True)))
delete_futures.extend(ndb.delete_multi_async(myModels.Kind2.query().fetch(999999, keys_only=True)))
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/futureclass#Future_wait_all

Comment: dargh! thanks... not really a GAE NDB question then but a lack of understanding of python lists. works now!

Answer (score 1):

each call to `delete_multi_async` returns a list of futures, so your `delete_futures` list is a list of lists. Change your `append`s to `extend` and it should work